# How to create a list of custom checkboxes in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, checkbox

I want to create a list of custom checkboxes(custom shape and color + icon) in flutter which can change their state on tap, till now I have created the list of checkboxes, but when I tap on one of them, all of them change their state.
I want that only the checkbox I'm tapping should change it's state.

```
 Widget checkbox(){
    return InkWell(                ///CHECKBOX
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          this.value = !this.value;
        });
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
        child:
        value ? Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.green),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.check,
              size: 20.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            )
        )
            :
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black, ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          child: Icon(
            Icons.circle,
            size: 30.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),

      ),
    );
```

Edit(s):

1. I've used Inkwell class for this purpose
2. 'value' is initialized to false

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your code so that we can figure the problem

Comment: @BesufkadMenji I've made the required edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put you checkbox in the separate stateful widget so that it can control it's own state

```
class MyCheckbox extends StatefulWidget {
MyCheckbox({Key key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_MyCheckboxState createState() => _MyCheckboxState();
}

class _MyCheckboxState extends State<MyCheckbox> {
 bool value = false;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(

    ///CHECKBOX
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        this.value = !this.value;
      });
    },
    child: Container(
      decoration:
          BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white),
      child: value
          ? Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.green),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.check,
                size: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
          : Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                size: 30.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
    ));
  }
 }
```

and when you call your widget add `key: UniqueKey(),` to make sure everything works as expected